# React Native FlatList doesn't show image after navigation.pop()

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Main technologies in play: `FlatList` `React-Navigation 5` `Redux` `Redux-Thunk`.

Main Home page is a Feed of Posts (image, caption, name etc.).  Upper right corner of home page is a Header Button that I press to go to the screen where I can create a Post.  This is where an image, caption or both would get added to my home page.

Below is my `FlatList` code for reference.  I have already tried to set `removeClippedSubviews={false}`.  Doing so doesn't work and actually makes the problem worse.

```
            <FlatList
                ref={flatListRef}
                data={allPosts} 
                extraData={[isLoading, isRefreshing, allPosts]}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl 
                        refreshing={isRefreshing}
                        onRefresh={onRefresh}
                    />
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item._id}
                initialNumToRender={2}
                renderItem={renderItem}

                onEndReached={!endOfFeed && !oneTimeLoad && handleLoadMore}
                onEndReachedThreshold={2}
                ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
                ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
                removeClippedSubviews={true} // Best way to optimize but sacrifices fast scroll down with blank space
                //getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({ length: POST_CARD_HEIGHT, offset: POST_CARD_HEIGHT * index, index})}
                //windowSize={20}

                //maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
                //updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
            />
```

My Stack Navigator is as shown before I press "Submit Post": `HomeScreen` => `CreatePostScreen`.  Pressing "Submit" in `CreatePostScreen` dispatches an action that makes an `API` call to my backend server.  Creates the post gets back the created post data including image `uri` and other `metadata` and then updates my redux state by prepending the newly created post to the old state.

I then make a call to `navigation.pop()` bringing me back to `HomeScreen`.  When I see it again I am met with a Post with all relevant data except **NO** image is showing.  I can see it only if I scroll down where it is out of view and then back to it.

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: will it be possible to show some code? If its too complex, pseudo code would be okay. Its a bit wordy and kinda hard to understand

Comment: Yeah I can add some psedo code and clarify better

Comment: @James tried to make it a little clearer and added my FlatList code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue related to my backend and how images get uploaded in general.

Because there is an AWSLambda function that converts uploaded images to different sizes for efficiency, popping back to the home feed immediately and trying to grab the just uploaded image resulted in a fail on the image load because it didn't exist yet in its resized format.

The Lambda runs pretty quickly but the state update was occurring faster.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the simple solution would be to use a different navigation method such as `navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')` or `navigation.replace('HomeScreen')`. You mentioned that if you scroll down past the post and then back up that the image reloads, so that makes me think using a different navigation might do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't `replace` just replace my current screen with a new one that I specified.  But leave my existing stack screens in place i.e. if I had S1 -> S2 -> S3 where S1 is 'HomeScreen'.  If I call `replace` my stack will look as S1 -> S2 -> S1 where now I have two HomeScreens in the Stack.